# Update Custom Attribute like Price with the subtotal in the minicart

Tags: product-attribute, addtocart, mini-cart, subtotal

I have created an attribute for the Product like some extra fees.

I got the attribute on the mini cart, saved it in the quote also updated their price according to the product quantity.

I want to include that price also in the subtotal in the mini cart.

When subtotal appears at the minicart it also includes this price.